# Do we need to test callback in ActiveRecord like after_destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, tdd

Do we need to test callback in ActiveRecord like `after_destroy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given something like this:

```
after_destroy :clean_up_some_stuff
```

I don't think you need to test that `after_destroy` works but you do need to fully test that the `clean_up_some_stuff` method functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can test 2 things here.

what the purpose of your method invoked after destroy `clean_up_some_stuff`

```
test "should do the clean up stuff" do
  assert Model.new.clean_up_some_stuff
  # more asserts to verify the job is done
end
```

Destroying the object and verifying the callback is successful

```
test "should destroy" do
  object = Model.create
  assert  object.destroy
  # more asserts to verify the job is done
end
```

[assertions-cheat-sheet](https://whatdoitest.com/rails-assertions-cheat-sheet) should be helpful.